# Python/Django: Schedule task in realtime after every X duration (secs/mins/hours?)

Tags: python, django, multithreading, django-celery

I want to execute some task (function) within my Django application at a specified duration from when a call is made to that. Something like:

```
... some code
async_run_func(time_interval=15_mins)  # Async call. Code within the function 
                                       # should be executed after 15 mins.
... some more code
```

`async_run_func` is to be executed after some custom interval.

What is the correct approach to achieve this? One way is to create a separate thread and sleep it for `time_duration` period. But that  will result into too many threads on the server. Also, in case the gunicorn process is restarted, the state will be lost. I want the information to persistent. So, I do not want to go with this approach. Currently I am using celery for executing long async and periodic tasks. But celery do not allow option to run a function single time after the specified duration.

It will be great if there is anyway to do it on distributed system. For example, function will be call from one system but the code to be executed on other system (use of queue like RabbitMQ is fine with me). Else, I can also go for executing it on the same machine. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ETA and Countdown](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown) are options to perform this using [django-celery](http://ask.github.io/celery/userguide/).

---

From the [document](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown):

> The **ETA (estimated time of arrival)** lets you set a specific date and time that is the earliest time at which your task will be executed. **countdown** is a shortcut to set ETA by seconds into the future.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> >>> result = add.apply_async((2, 2), countdown=3)
> >>> result.get()    # this takes at least 3 seconds to return
> 20
> ```

The task is guaranteed to be executed at some time after the specified date and time, but not necessarily at that exact time. Possible reasons for broken deadlines may include many items waiting in the queue, or heavy network latency. To make sure your tasks are executed in a timely manner you should monitor the queue for congestion.

> While countdown is an integer, eta must be a datetime object, specifying an exact date and time (including millisecond precision, and timezone information):
>
> ```
> >>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>
> >>> tomorrow = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=1)
> >>> add.apply_async((2, 2), eta=tomorrow)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Celery has the option of enqueuing at a specific time:

```
your_async_function.apply_async(args=(your, args, tuple),
                                kwargs={your: kwargs},
                                countdown=15 * 60)
```

Or use the subtask syntax, to curry all args and then delay

```
your_async_function.s(your, args, tuple, your: kwargs).delay(countdown=15 * 60)
```

If the function has no args, you can skip them and do directly

```
your_async_function.delay(countdown=15 * 60)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

What about using `sched` module? Simple and efficient.

```
import sched, time

sc = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
sc.enter(15, 1, async_run_func, ())
sc.run
```

Comment: `sched` is not thread safe in multithreaded environment. And, I wanted the solution which I can execute on distributed machines. Celery's `countdown` is exactly what I was looking for. + I am already having celery configured on my machines. But as per the question, since we can schedule a function by using sched. +1 for you.